# Javascript onMouseDown function, testing when you have left clicked

Tags: javascript

```
setInterval(mouse, 20);  

function mouse(){
        if(onMouseDown == true){
            //Code for when you are holding mouse down
        }else{
            //Code for when the mouse isn't being held
        }
    }
```

This is the basic idea for my code. When the left mouse button is being held down I want it to execute set code, then when the mouse is not down it to preform another task. How do I do this. Thank you :)

Comment: The term "left button" should probably be "primary button", since that is the term the [Events Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#widl-MouseEvent-button) uses. Pointing devices may not have a logical left or right button, and may have any button configured to be the primary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the mousedown and mouseup events along with setInterval/clearInterval

```
(function(){
   var downTimer = null;
   var upTimer = null;
   function runWhileDown(){
      //code to run while mouse is down
   }
   function runWhileUp(){
      //code to run while mouse is up
   }
   document.addEventListener("mousedown",function(){
      //Stop the runWhileUp code from running
      if(upTimer) clearInterval(upTimer);
      //make sure the previous interval is stopped
      if(downTimer) clearInterval(downTimer);
      //start the new timer
      downTimer = setInterval(runWhileDown,20);
   });
   document.addEventListener("mouseup",function(){
      //Stop the runWhileDown code from running
      if(downTimer) clearInterval(downTimer);
      //make sure the previous interval is stopped
      if(upTimer) clearInterval(upTimer);
      //start the new timer
      upTimer = setInterval(runWhileUp,20);
   });
   //If you need the runWhileUp code to run at the start
   upTimer = setInterval(runWhileUp,20);
})();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2kZEw/)

Comment: If I only want this to work on a certain canvas would i just change document to var c6=document.getElementById("cloud"); c6? @patrick Evans

Comment: That's why my answer (the one below) is better. More flexibility and much simpler. :-)

Comment: @reidjako yes if you want it to happen for the canvas replace it with the canvas element.

Comment: @reidjako Also note that if this is for doing animations in the canvas, use `requestAnimationFrame` instead of intervals

Comment: @chris97ong, your solution only allows for executing once every time the click happens or relased, it does not continually run while the mouse is down or up

Comment: *mousedown* and *mouseup* will be dispatched if any button is pressed. Since the OP wants the left (primary) button, the code should check the related event property to see which button has been pressed. The related event properties are pretty messed up, see [*Which mouse button has been clicked*](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html).

Comment: @PatrickEvans Pls see edit. Now it only works for left mouse button

Answer (score 3):

```
function detectLeftButton(evt) {
   evt = evt || window.event;
   var btn = evt.which || evt.button;
   return (btn == 1);
}
document.onmousedown = function() {
   if(detectLeftButton(this.event)) {
   // Code when mouse is down
   }
}

document.onmouseup = function() {
   if(detectLeftButton(this.event)) {
   // Code when mouse is not held
   }
}
```

In the above code when the person presses his left mouse button down anywhere in the webpage, code will be run and when he presses it up, another set of code will be executed. [Fiddle (updated)](http://jsfiddle.net/chris97ong/Qcr6w/2/).

Learn more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmousedown.asp).

Hope that helps.

Comment: *which* and *button* aren't interchangeable like that. For *button*, the [Events Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#widl-MouseEvent-button) says the primary is `0`, whereas for *which* (and Microsoft's implementation of *button*), it will be `1`. There's a good article at [*http://unixpapa.com/js/mouse.html*](http://unixpapa.com/js/mouse.html).